# Cannot to connect to SQL Server using FreeTDS and ODBC (raspberry pi raspbian)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raspbian, pyodbc, freetds

Using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian 9, I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL database using ODBC (pip installed it from the shell) with FreeTDS (version 108)

Up until now, I have tried the following:

In `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

In my `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[name]
 Driver=FreeTDS
 ServerName = {MyServerString from Azure MS-SQL}
 Database = {My database name from Azure MSQ-SQL}
 TDS_Version = auto
```

In the `FreeTDS.config` file:

Created this block:

```
[name]
 host = {MyServerString from Azure MSQ SQL}
 port = 1433
 tds version = auto
```

When I run the following command:

```
tsql -S {name} -U {my_username} -P {my_password}
```

I get the result

```
No errors ( 1> )
```

So I believe I am connected to the database.

However, when I run my Python code. I get an error. My database connection block is below

```
#Database setup
conDEBUG = "DRIVER={FreeTDS};Database={MyDGName};SERVER=tcp:{MyDB}.database.windows.net;UID={myUID};PWD={myPWD}"
conDEBUG = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conDEBUG)
conDEBUG = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % conDEBUG
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conDEBUG
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I also tried adding 'TDS_Version=auto' to the conDEBUG string, this didn't work either.

The specific error I am getting:

> ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Try removing `tcp:` from `SERVER=tcp:{MyDB}.database.windows.net`. `protocol:servername` is supported by Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server, but not by FreeTDS ODBC.

Comment: Tried it. No success.. same error

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use for connecting via SQLAlchemy to SQL Server over `pyodbc`:

```
def mssql_connect(con_string): 
    """ Connects to the specified db via ODBC. """
    def connect():
        return pyodbc.connect(con_string, autocommit=True)

    db = create_engine('mssql://', creator=connect, encoding='cp1252')
    db.echo = False

    return db

mssql_connect("DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER={MyDB}.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE={dbname};UID={myUID};PWD={myPWD};TDS_Version=7.3;")
```

Depending on your version of FreeTDS, you may have to replace `TDS_Version=7.3` with `TDS_Version=7.2` or `TDS_Version=7.1`. Good luck!